# Changing an iframe SRC dynamically

Tags: javascript, iframe

What I have and I need to do it work properly is when I'm in a "start page" and I click a button like this:

**PAGE-1**

```
<a href="/PAGE-2/" data-iframe-src="http://myappwebsite/resourcesiframe?shopId=3366&type=image&max-levels=1&point=A" class="map-button">Point A</a>
```

It should send me to "another page" where I load dinamically an iframe taking each variable (shopID, type, max-levels and point) from the URL and print it like an iframe this way:

**PAGE-2**

```
<iframe id="frame" src="http://myappwebsite/resourcesiframe?shopId=3366&type=image&point=A" width=“XXX" height=“XXX"></iframe>
```

I've used this javascript snippet but anyway, I can't make it work properly at all.

```js
$(".map-button").click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
$("#frame").attr("src", $(this).attr('data - iframe - src'));
});
```

I only need to get the variables from the data-iframe-src and use them in the iframe, but I'm not able... The problem is that I load elements in different pages, so I don't  know how this affect to the URL variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: You can't affect an element on a new page that hasn't even loaded within the click handler. When new page loads it is a whole new window instance and knows nothing about the script in previous page

Comment: Do you actually need to read any query string parameters here, or do you just need to load the URL given in the `data-iframe-src` attribute into the iframe directly? (You say you wanted to take over `max-levels` as well, but then your example leaves that parameter out.)

Comment: @CBroe I need to load the URL given in the `data-iframe-src` into the iframe directly. But this is my aproach, I don't know if the best way is with `data-iframe-src`. This is an attribute I use in my PAGE-1 button to send attributes to the PAGE-2. And `max-levels` parameter is out in this example because it's not important for now.

Comment: _“And max-levels parameter is out in this example because it's not important for now”_ - but it changes the whole scope of the question, so please try and be precise in such regards next time! // As @charlietfl already said, it can’t work this way, you have a logic issue here. When you follow the link to `/PAGE-2/`, then your browser would load that page, and therefor your `a` element that you want to read the `data-iframe-src` attribute value from, doesn’t even exist any more.

Comment: You need to either stay on the current page (which also contains your iframe), or you would need to pass this value over to a “different page” some other way first, for example as a GET parameter, so that you could then read that from inside page 2 ...

Comment: @charlietfl so it's impossible to call a PAGE-2 from PAGE-1 sending a parameter from PAGE-1 to insert it into an iframe in PAGE-2?

Comment: No it's not impossible if you use url parameters and read those on new page as @CBroe pointed out. Or you could store values in localStorage and read from there. Both require you to assign the iframe src from inside the secong page code

Answer (score 0):

I've founded a simple solution for my problem here and it works for me.

First of all I put this simple iframe in my PAGE-2:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Then in PAGE-1 I've used this type of links:

```
https://myappwebsite/page-2?shopId=1234&type=image&max-levels=1&point=A
```

So now my PAGE-2 loads properly with these params in the URL. Then I've used this simple snippet in Javascript to fill my iframe in PAGE-2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#frame").attr("src", "https://myappwebsite/resourcesiframe" + window.location.search);
    });
</script>
```

And it works! Now I can go to PAGE-2 with all my params, pick them and use them in SRC inside the blank iframe.

Thanks for getting me in the correct path!